# How do I load environment variables for a phoenix framework project

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I created a Phoenix app then added the bamboo module for sending email, and I successfully sent my first email using Elixir this afternoon, but I had to hard code the *username* and *password* into the `config.exs`.

I read [this article](https://medium.com/@kkomaz/phoenix-setting-up-env-variables-6557eb1370ee#.qom4j63yb) and set up a .env file in the root of my phoenix project, and I am trying to load the environment variables using the following statement(s), within the `config.exs` file.

```elixir
username: System.get_env("SMTP_USERNAME"),
password: System.get_env("SMTP_PASSWORD"),
```

However, the emails are not being sent, and bamboo is giving me a rather cryptic error message.

I am building the phoenix app using the following command from the terminal,

```bash
iex -S mix
```

and I'm manually sending the emails within a iex session with a command similar to the one below,

```elixir
CrjApi.Email.hello_text_email("me@example.com") |> CrjApi.Mailer.deliver_now
```

but the emails are only being sent when the username / password are hard coded into the `config.exs` file.  How can I use the `.env` file I setup so I don't have to hard code the username / password into the `config.exs`?

***Note:*** I'm running OS X, and using the fish shell.

Comment: If you go into `iex` and type `System.get_env("SMTP_USERNAME")`, do you get the expected value? Do the same for the password.

Comment: @JustinWood the command you suggested is returning `nil`.  And thanks for pointing me in the right direction ;)

Comment: The article is working if you strictly follow every step. Still there is a typo in `source .env`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up creating a `smtp.exs` file within `config` directory which looks like the following,

**smtp.exs**

```
use Mix.Config

config :crj_api, CrjApi.Mailer,
  username: "foo",
  password: "secret_password"
```

and then added the following to `config.exs`

`import_config "smtp.exs"`

Now when I load the application with `iex -S mix` it loads in these application variables everytime, and I don't have source an environment variable for each terminal session.

Comment: I recommend add this file to `.gitignore`

Answer (score 10):

You can use confex module in your project.
https://github.com/Nebo15/confex

This is a helper module that provides you with the option to read env configuration at runtime.

config.exs example

```
config :app_name,
  smtp_username:  {:system, "SMTP_USERNAME", "default_user_name"},
  smtp_password:  {:system, "SMTP_PASSWORD", "default_password"}
```

In your module

```
username = Confex.get(:app_name, :smtp_username)
password = Confex.get(:app_name, :smtp_password)
```

Into your iex type

```
System.put_env("SMTP_USERNAME", "real_username")
System.put_env("SMTP_PASSWORD", "real_password")
```

Answer (score 8):

You can put all your environment variables in a file named for example `.env.dev` or `.env.prod` (don't forget to add `.env.*` to .gitignore file):

```
export SMTP_DOMAIN=smtp.trumpy.xyz
export SMTP_USERNAME=donny@trumpy.xyz
export SMTP_PASSWORD=donny123
export SMTP_PORT=587
...
```

Load that file and run Phoenix server:

```
source .env.dev && mix phx.server
```

Remember to use this syntax

```
port: {:system, "SMTP_PORT"},
username: {:system, "SMTP_USERNAME"},
```

In place of this

```
port: System.get_env("SMTP_PORT"),
username: System.get_env("SMTP_USERNAME"),
```

in order to load ENV variables at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Like the article you wrote about, I use ENV vars for Phoenix from my System. Just create them via export:

`export SMTP_USERNAME=you_variable`

and so on and Phoenix will se them and get at the start server time.
Also there is possible to use .env file, but I only use it with 'heroku local'.

Check this hex [dotenv_elixir](https://github.com/avdi/dotenv_elixir) but it realy not elixir way.

Comment: He doesn't specify if he's on Windows or Mac OSX/Linux. The command would be `SET SMTP_USERNAME=your_variable` on the off-chance he's on Windows.